# SBJson Stream Parser crashes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, web-services, sbjson

I am working on a webservice in Json with SBJson.

When I receive something like that there is no problem :

```
{"error":"The operation failed"}
```

But When I receive something like that, it crashes the app :

```
[{"id":"29"}]
```

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please show your code, and note where the crash occurs. My guess is that it will be where you read the result, not in the parser itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `{"error":"The operation failed"}` and `[{"id":"29"}]`:

- the first one is Object (an unordered collection of key:value pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value, comma-separated and enclosed in curly braces; the keys must be strings and should be distinct from each other);
- the second one is Array (an ordered sequence of values, comma-separated and enclosed in square brackets; the values do not need to be of the same type).

In your app, you handle JSON response in Dictionary - which suits for `{"error":"The operation failed"}` case, but is wrong for second case (which is an array) - `[{"id":"29"}]`.

(With dictionary you can execute `- objectForKey:` , and with array `- objectAtIndex:` ).

To understand, how it works, you can read more about JSON:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON